# Туториал для распростронения SQL CLR приложений

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, развертывание, sqlclr

Создал некоторые SQL CLR Функции и процедуры в Visual Studio 2013.

Теперь нужно подготовить скрипт sql для распростронения функционала.
При этом скрипт должен обновлять assemblies в базе или добавлять их, если они в базе данных не присутствуют. То же самое с CLR функциями и процедурами.

Хотелось бы, что бы студия генерировала скрипт сама, но она это делает лишь частично, а имено геренирует скрипт на основе текущей базы данных. Т.е., если функция уже присутсвует в базе данных, создание функции не просходит.

Как привильно настроить студию на необходимый вывод?

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение - при генерации скрипта указывать студии в качестве цели пустую базу данных. Это приведет к генерации скрипта для создания базы с нуля.

Править имя базы в свойствах проекта каждый раз неудобно, так что проще генерировать скрипт деплоя через MSBuild - из консоли или из билд-скрипта.

Пример proj-файла:

Создание чистой базы:

```xml
<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.SqlExecute ConnectionString="Data Source=$(TargetDatabaseServer);Integrated Security=true;"
                Command="CREATE DATABASE [$(TargetDatabase)]" >
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="SqlResult" />
</MSBuild.Community.Tasks.SqlExecute>
```

Деплой с генерацией скрипта:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <DatabaseProjectBuildProperties>Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU;TargetConnectionString=$(TargetConnectionString);TargetDatabaseName=$(TargetDatabase);UpdateDatabase=False;</DatabaseProjectBuildProperties>
</PropertyGroup>

<MSBuild Targets="Build;Deploy" Projects="@(DatabaseProjectsToDeploy)" 
    Properties="$(DatabaseProjectBuildProperties)" />
```